# Magento fieldset type 'image' doesn't show up in $_FILES

Tags: image, magento, magento-1.7, image-uploading

Strange thing in my Magento. And I can't see the problem.

I've created a module. (it extends the CMS pages)

In the `Observer.php` I've got:

```
$fieldset->addField('news_header_image', 'image', array(
    'name'      => 'news_header_image',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('News Header image 80x80 pics'),
    'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('News Header image 80x80 pics'),
    'value'     => $model['news_header_image']
));
```

This works *fine*, but...

In my observer.php `public function savePage(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)`

I *can* use: `$_POST['news_header_image']`
*but* `$_FILES['news_header_image']['name']` (or even `var_dump($_FILES)` ) is completely empty :-S

What is wrong here? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the enctype to the `<form>` of the cms page

```
/**
 * Add enctype to cms page edit form
 *
 * @param $observer Varien_Event_Observer
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function adminhtmlBlockHtmlBefore($observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Edit_Form) {
        $block->getForm()->setEnctype('multipart/form-data');
    }
}
```

and add this to your config:

```
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_block_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <threeaart_pagetemplates>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>ThreeAArt_PageTemplates_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>adminhtmlBlockHtmlBefore</method>
                    </threeaart_pagetemplates>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_block_html_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be getting any values attached by the event using the observer object rather than directly via _POST variables.

I'm not familiar with CMS Events, but if you do a debug dump of the below to see what values are available in your particular event..

```
$observer->getEvent()
```

Comment: Ow, jeah, thanks! It shows up here. But then the last question would be... How to get it in this one?

`$uploader->save($media_path, $file_name . $_FILES['news_header_image']['name']);` I guess this has to be changed... but into what? `$_FILES['news_header_image']['name']`